# MacBook Pro - issues connecting to external monitor(both DisplayPort and HDMI)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi, displayport

I have an Apple Macbook Pro 16 Inch (Touchbar) 2019 w/ AMD Radeon Pro 5300M. I'm running into issues connecting it to this monitor, [PX329](https://pixiogaming.com/products/px329).

If I use DisplayPort(this monitor supports up to version 1.2) then my mouse starts to lag/skip which is really annoying.

If I use an HDMI cord, with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THJGZ9Z) adapter, my external screen goes black about every 20-30 minutes for a second or two and then back to normal. I'm using 2560x1440 resolution on my external monitor w/ 50 Hertz refresh rate(I tried 60, same thing).

At this point I'm not sure what I should buy. I'm considering either:

1. Get this [DisplayPort cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075V27G2R) or
2. Get an HDMI to USB-C cord without an adapter.

Could you please recommend what's better, I'm not really sure what specs I should check on the monitor to figure out which route to go.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor?

Comment: No, but this is my main monitor. I need to get it working on this one. I never had any issues with it when using my other laptop or my Desktop.

Comment: I understand you want it working on this monitor.  But first you need to diagnose where the problem lies.  Is it computer, cable, or monitor? First steps are to try different monitors and cables to see if it effects all monitors and cables or just specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out in case anyone runs into a similar annoying issue.

I went ahead and ordered both a new 4k Mac supported [USBC-HDMI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083Z8QBJ5) cable and also same for [USBC-DisplayPort](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075V27G2R).

The display port cable caused the exact same issue, mouse was lagging. When I plugged in the HDMI cable all issues went away and it works great. So basically I couldn't use the aforementioned HDMI adapter and just needed to get a USBC-HDMI cable.

Thanks.